# Internet Explorer 8 não carrega o CSS

Tags: css, magento, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Estou trabalhando em uma loja virtual alterando seu layout, porem o CSS que tenho alterado é o `skin/frontend/meutema/default/css/style.css`. Até ai tudo certo, Chrome carrega minhas alterações normal, Firefox também, e IE9 ou superior também.

Porém o IE8 para baixo, ele não carrega o CSS, tudo perde o estilo exceto o menu. Tentei alterar o arquivo, `style-ie` mas nada adianta.

Comment: O ficheiro deve estar a ser carregado com certeza no entanto muitos estilos de css só estão "disponiveis" para o IE apartir de certas versões do browser. Para os casos em que os estilos não são aplicados, é necessário forçar a sua atribuição e para isso usa-se o `*` antes dos estilos, o `!important` depois dos estilos, o `-ms` antes dos estilos, etc. Tudo depende dos estilos que você quer aplicar. Você não pode apresentar o código do seu ficheiro css?

Comment: Então eu uso metodos como !important para forcar a utilização de certo estilo porem apartir do ie8, ele nao perde so os estilos, lista de produtos na home se quebram ficando uma embaixo da outra, como se nao carregasse nenhum css. O codigo seria minha folha de estilos que estou utilizando ?

Comment: sim, o código seria a folha de estilos que está usando. O `!important`só funciona em alguns casos, bem como o `*` e outras opções

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância, mas aonde vc adicionou esse código?

Answer (score 1):

Muito obrigado a quem ajudou, mas descobri o problema:

1º - é que como o templete é reponsivo o IE nao estava lendo as medias query pesquisei e coloquei este codigo

```
[if lt IE 9]
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js" />
[endif]
```

2º - é que havia um IF em comentario que so buscava o CSS styles.css caso fosse IE9 ou superior, entao alterei para que carregasse em qualquer IE ai funcionou, agora basta fazer algumas alterações no CSS somente.